# What to do if certain parameters are not market observable?

Tags: option-pricing, equities, derivatives, risk-management, parameter-estimation

Lets say I have no clue on correlation between 2 equities in the market (i.e. i don't have an observable market price). What is the best way to go about marking this correlation for lets say the best of option? One alternative is historical data but that's not the same as realised correlation. Should I mark it conservatively? Use some proxy?

Comment: You can turn to model free proxies by using options-based implied moments (like VIX). If you look for Ian Martin's papers, you will find some good stuff about model free covariance. From there, move to model free implied correlation. You'll need option chains from the "market" (e.g. an index) and from every single stock in it.

Comment: @Lisa Ann The option data would be informative about the Q measure, but not the P measure absent some structure imposed on the pricing kernel. Notice that this is also true of the shocking result Martin derived in his QJE paper.

Comment: If your purpose is to value derivatives, then possible choices are: 1) use the market-implied correlation for a similar pair, for example proxy BMW-Tesla correlation with Audi-Tesla correlation, or perform an historical correlation analysis to identify similar pairs; 2) use historical correlation using e.g. 2-year worth of data; 3) mark conservatively, maybe identify an approximate proxy and scale it appropriately for prudence. I've seen all these 3 choices being used in practice - particularly in correlation, which at least in IR is not very liquid for most pairs.

Answer (score 1):

If I know some relevant fundamental ratios for these two equities, I might take inspiration from [MSCI's](https://www.msci.com/documents/10199/606f2b8e-94a9-4793-b0f1-dce994171fe9) predicted beta, which to me means that I would look for other equity pairs whose correlations I know, and see if their fundamentals ratios explain their correlations, and predict what my pairs correlation might be.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "historical data is not the same as realized correlation"? If you compute historical correlation, it will be the historical realised correlation. Of course it will probably differ from future realized correlation. But if there was some implied correlation market there would be no reason for implied to be in line with future realized as well. It's just market expectation.
Now if there is no implied market on this correlation, just like if you try to price an option on an underlier without an implied vol market, you would use some reasonably conservative (because you still want to win the trade) educated guess on what the future realized correlation will be. This guess can be based on historical analysis, a view on the future, an implied proxy, etc...

Comment: Suppose a stock just went public and has no history yet...